# For hashing, what happens to number of empty slots when n tends to inifinity?

Tags: algorithm, hash

Under universal hashing assumption, if i have hash table of size ***m=cn***, ***c*>0**, and as ***n*** tends to infinity, what does the number of empty slots tend to?

I'm a bit stuck on how to do this because ***m*** is a function of ***n***...(the answer I get for different values of m too) is always tending to infinity and I'm not exactly sure if that is accurate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a specific cell *i*. The probability that all keys missed it is

*((m - 1) / m)<sup>n</sup> = (1 - 1/m)<sup>n</sup> = (1 - 1/m)<sup>m/c</sup> ~ e<sup>-1/c</sup>*.

(For the last approximation, see [representations of *e*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_representations_of_e).)

The event that all keys missed some other specific cell *j* is *not* independent, but by [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity), that doesn't matter. The expected number of empty bins will be *m* multiplied by the previous expression.